Private Endpoints and Azure Bot Services

disable public access

Currently; Without internet access and private endpoints enabled; I am no longer able to view azure bot services in our test view.. Basically it is not recognizing the new directline url; NSG, private endpoints and direct line are all configured according to microsoft spec; is there a caveat I am missing? DNS zone is present, all subnet accordingly.. Is there something special here?
I was expecting it to work by setting private endpoints, disable public access, and using directline
